# contradictory messages after having created a system image on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-backup

I have created a "system image" of my C: hard drive on an external hard drive. At the end of the system image creation I got a successful message in the popup where the blue progress bar was.

But on the backup & restore windows I have this alert:

[image]

In the  I did not find any error neither in the event viewer, nor any success message. I'm a bit confuse...

Any idea which message I should trust? 
Is there a way to check the system image?

Answer (score 1):

That error is referring to your last scheduled backup (19/10/2014 @ 19:00) not the System Image backup you just did manually.

Comment: It's embarrassing, my bad! But I still don't get any success in the event viewer, any idea why?

Comment: Is this behavior documented somewhere?